# When is $\frac{n-13}{5n+6}$ Reducible?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Find the least positive integer n for which $\frac{n-13}{5n+6}$ is a non-zero reducible fraction.

I've just begun working with NT problems, and I'm not quite sure how I should approach this without just testing values.  Could I get some help?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** This is equivalent to asking for the least $n$ such that $\gcd(n-13,5n+6)$ is greater than 1. Do you know how to reduce $\gcd$ - like the fact that
$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$$
because using that rule (repeatedly) one can find that $\gcd(n-13,5n+6)$ is equal to the $\gcd$ of $n-13$ and a *constant* - which is much easier to solve.

Answer (score 0):

If a fraction will cancel, it means that the numerator and denominator has a gcd greater than 1.

To find values of $n$ like this, use the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm). Assuming $a=qb+r$ (for integers $a$, $b$, $q$, $r$, where $a\ge b>r\ge0$), then:
$$
\gcd(a, b)=\gcd(b,r)
$$
By applying the Euclidean algorithm repeatedly on $a=n-13$ and $b=5n+6$, you will eventually end up with a gcd of a constant and n-13. Then you can figure it out easily.